# player dies after clicking play button but i want him to die if not trigger enemy collider for more than 2 secs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a chasing game where if player is on the enemy collision range it gets score but if the player is not in the enemy zone after 2 seconds he dies but here the unity is showing that touching value is true but after clicking play player dies after 2secs even when the bool value is true and he should be dying if the bool value is false.
welp stuck on this code for hours ;-;

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
  {
  public GameObject other;
  bool touching;
  int score = 0;


  public void Update()
 {
    AddScore();
 
 }


 private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D Other)
 {
   Debug.Log("Touching");
   touching = true;
 }

 public void AddScore()
 {

 if(touching == true)
 {
 score++;
 StartCoroutine(wait());
 }
 else
 {
 Debug.Log("Not Touching");
 StartCoroutine(waiter());
 }

 }

 IEnumerator waiter()
 {

 yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
 Destroy(other);
 }

 IEnumerator wait()
 {
 yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);

 }

 }
```

Comment: First of all without indentation it is difficult for us to read the code and therefore it is difficult to help you. Then you have to figure out if at the beginning of the game the chaser is already within range or not. In any case, you should declare touching as true or false, unless you are sure that OnTriggerStay2D() happens before Update(). Then if it is not within range, you should probably ask yourself at the end of the two seconds if it has reached it again, otherwise as soon as it comes out it dies automatically after two seconds, even if it then re-reaches it

Comment: When you start the game is the player inside the 2DCollider? If not then the 'touching' bools default value of false, will cause your waiter coroutine to fire on the first frame, which will result in the other object being destroyed in 2 seconds. If you want the player to be able to stop this when they get in the collider, then you need to perform another check after waiting 2 seconds to see if the bool is true. Just because the player is now touching, you have nothing to stop the current coroutine from continuing its execution